# Oracle SQL - left join record with closest datetime

Tags: sql, oracle

I have 2 tables.

table1:

| item | end time |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022-11-23 08:12:00 |
| 1 | 2022-11-23 09:12:00 |
| 2 | 2022-11-22 13:12:00 |
| 3 | 2022-11-22 14:12:00 |

table2:

| item | value | last_dt |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 11 | 2022-11-23 09:12:00 |
| 1 | 12 | 2022-11-23 08:30:00 |
| 1 | 13 | 2022-11-24 08:30:00 |
| 2 | 21 | 2022-11-22 13:12:00 |
| 3 | 31 | 2022-11-22 14:12:00 |
| 3 | 32 | 2022-11-22 14:30:00 |

i would like to left join table1 to table2 by comparing the table1's end_time with table2's last_dt.

below is the expected result.

| item | end time | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022-11-23 08:12:00 | 12 |
| 1 | 2022-11-23 09:12:00 | 11 |
| 2 | 2022-11-22 13:12:00 | 21 |
| 3 | 2022-11-22 14:12:00 | 31 |

Comment: As per question guideline, please do not post images! Please convert it to text. Also, please share with us what you've tried and provide DDL + DML command

Comment: @Lee: Please DO NOT change questions after they have already been answered correctly. No one can replicate this, especially if you repeat this multiple times. This can cause never-ending stories with 20 answers and no one understands why the first 19 answers are incorrect. Please upvote answers that helped you for your original question, accept one of them, undo your changes and create a new question for your new situation.

Comment: After changing your description, you do NOT want to fetch those rows with the minimum date difference. You want to exlcude those rows with the maximum difference where dates are different. This is a completely other question which as said requires a new question instead of changing the original one.

Comment: @JonasMetzler So the original question *may* require clarification. My first reading was "fetch closest row from lookup table for each row of `table1`" which is valid and quite clear and doesn't differ from the current content

Answer (score 0):

Preparing

```
-- ms-sql-syntax
create table table1(item# int, end_time datetime);
insert table1 select 1, '2022-11-23T08:12:00';
insert table1 select 2, '2022-11-22T13:12:00';
insert table1 select 3, '2022-11-22T14:12:00';

create table table2 (item# int, value int, end_time datetime);
insert table2 select 1, 11, '2022-11-23T09:12:00';
insert table2 select 1, 12, '2022-11-23T08:30:00';
insert table2 select 1, 13, '2022-11-24T08:30:00';
insert table2 select 2, 21, '2022-11-22T13:12:00';
insert table2 select 3, 31, '2022-11-22T14:12:00';
insert table2 select 3, 32, '2022-11-22T14:30:00';
```

expected result

```
item# end_time            value
1     2022-11-23 08:12:00 12
2     2022-11-22 13:12:00 21
3     2022-11-22 14:12:00 31
```

**Second**

You do not need "left join". You need "outer apply" or "cross apply"
https://oracle-base.com/articles/12c/lateral-inline-views-cross-apply-and-outer-apply-joins-12cr1#cross-apply-join

It should be something like this:

```
-- it should be oracle syntax. not sure
SELECT
    t1.item#, t1.end_time, t2.value
FROM table1 AS t1
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT value
    FROM table2 AS t2ca
    WHERE rownum = 1
    ORDER BY ABS(@DATEDIFF('SS', t2ca.end_time, t1.end_time))
) AS t2

-- ms-sql-syntax. exactly
SELECT
    t1.item#, t1.end_time, t2.value
FROM table1 AS t1
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT top 1 value
    FROM table2 AS t2ca
    ORDER BY ABS(DATEDIFF(second, t2ca.end_time, t1.end_time))
) AS t2
```

TOP 1 WITH TIES -- ms-sql-syntax

```
-- TOP 1 WITH TIES -- ms-sql-syntax
SELECT TOP 1 WITH TIES
    t1.item#
    , t1.end_time
    , t2.value
FROM table1 AS t1
CROSS JOIN table2 AS t2
ORDER BY
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
        PARTITION BY t1.item#, t1.end_time
        ORDER BY ABS(DATEDIFF(second, t2.end_time, t1.end_time))
    );
```

SUBQUERY and window-ROW_NUMBER() -- ms-sql-syntax

```
-- SUBQUERY and window-ROW_NUMBER() -- ms-sql-syntax
SELECT 
    item#
    , end_time
    , value
FROM ( 
    SELECT 
        t1.item#
        , t1.end_time
        , t2.value
        , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
            PARTITION BY t1.item#, t1.end_time
            ORDER BY ABS(DATEDIFF (second, t2.end_time, t1.end_time))
        ) AS __rn__
    FROM table1 AS t1
    CROSS JOIN table2 AS t2
) AS ordering
WHERE __rn__ = 1
```

Comment: will not be able to use CROSS APPLY as the oracle version is below 12c

Answer (score 0):

You may use `lateral` join with `fetch first row only` to select the closest value per row. But it effectively will perform a nested loop (which would be fast in case of index on `item, last_dt` and small `table1`).

```
select *
from table1
  left join lateral (
    select value
    from table2
    where table2.item = table1.item
    order by abs(table2.last_dt - table1.end_time) asc
    fetch first row only
  ) val
  on 1 = 1
```

Alternatively you may use `first` aggregate function and order by time difference. It would work in old Oracle versions (at least from 10g) also.

```
select
  table1.item,
  table1.end_time,
  max(table2.value) keep(dense_rank first order by abs(table2.last_dt - table1.end_time)) as value
from table1
  left join table2
  on table2.item = table1.item
group by
  table1.item,
  table1.end_time
```

For your sample data both will return this result:

| ITEM | END_TIME | VALUE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022-11-23 08:12:00 | 12 |
| 2 | 2022-11-22 13:12:00 | 21 |
| 3 | 2022-11-22 14:12:00 | 31 |

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/2LYG03DA)